# Match by preferred relationship attribute in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In a large graph I would like to select the recursive paths, where the relationship matches either value B or value C, like here below

`match path=(a:item)-[rel:refers*]->(aa:item) where rel.name= 'B' or rel.name='C'  return path`

The above statement returns **all** the items when the relationship matches both values, I would like to choose the rel.name = 'B' relationship **and only** if rel.name='B' does not exist go for rel.name='C'

Is there a way to define this in Cypher, rather than returning everything and then filtering out the unwanted items ?

Thanks

Comment: Your Cypher query should be causing a "Type mismatch" syntax error (because `rel` is a *list* of relationships, not a relationship). Can you show your actual Cypher query?

Comment: Sure here it is: and there is not any Type mismatch syntax error  match path=(a:item)-[rel:refers]->(aa:item)
where rel.name= 'B' or rel.name='C' 
return path

Comment: Can you correct your question?